# Correct way to convert DataTable with duplicate values to Dictionary(of String, List(of Object)) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I am trying to convert a datatable to a dictionary. The table format is as follows:

```
ValueID | DependentValueID | DependencyDescription
__________________________________________________
A       | a                | some text
A       | b                | some text
B       | c                | some text
B       | d                | some text
B       | e                | some text
...
```

Each object has 3 properties:

1. ValueID
2. DependentValueID
3. DependencyDescription

The Dictionary format is as follows:

```
(Key) | (Value)
_______________
A    |  {
     |    [ 
     |      ValueID = A
     |      DependentValueID = a
     |      DependencyDescription = "some text"
     |    ], 
     |    [ 
     |      ValueID = A
     |      DependentValueID = b
     |      DependencyDescription = "some text"
     |    ], 
     |  }
-----------------------------------------------
B    |  {
     |    [ 
     |      ValueID = B
     |      DependentValueID = c
     |      DependencyDescription = "some text"
     |    ], 
     |    [ 
     |      ValueID = B
     |      DependentValueID = d
     |      DependencyDescription = "some text"
     |    ], 
     |    [ 
     |      ValueID = B
     |      DependentValueID = e
     |      DependencyDescription = "some text"
     |    ] 
     |  }
...
```

The code I wrote to do this:

```
Private Sub MySub()
    ' Declare variables and fill datatables   
    If DependenciesDataTable IsNot Nothing AndAlso DependenciesDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To DependenciesDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
            DependenciesObject.ValueID = DependenciesDataTable.Rows(i).Item("ValueID").ToString
            DependenciesObject.DependentValueID = DependenciesDataTable.Rows(i).Item("DependentValueID").ToString
            DependenciesObject.DependencyDescription = DependenciesDataTable.Rows(i).Item("DependencyDescription").ToString

            If i > 0 Then
                If DependenciesDataTable.Rows(i).Item("ValueID").ToString.Equals(DependenciesDataTable.Rows(i - 1).Item("ValueID").ToString) Then
                    DependenciesObject.Add(DependenciesObject)
                Else
                    DependenciesDictionary.Add(DependenciesDataTable.Rows(i - 1).Item("ValueID").ToString, DependenciesObject)
                    DependenciesObject = New List(Of Object)
                    DependenciesObject.Add(DependenciesObject)
                End If
            ElseIf i = 0 Then
                DependenciesObject.Add(DependenciesObject)
            End If

            If i = DependenciesDataTable.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                DependenciesObject.Add(DependenciesObject)
                DependenciesDictionary.Add(DependenciesDataTable.Rows(i).Item("ValueID").ToString, DependenciesObject)
                DependenciesObject = New List(Of Object)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Though this works, I understand that it is a subpar solution since I am a junior developer. I would like some advice on how to improve my approach to the issue.

Comment: If you've got working code, the place to ask about improving it is [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for the suggestion, I did not know about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that `dependenciesObject` is a `List(Of Object)`, but why? Use classes, or even something more temporary like Tuple... My solution will use a class to hold your dependency

```vb
Public Class Dependency
    Public Property ValueID As String
    Public Property DependentValueID As String
    Public Property DependencyDescription As String
End Class
```

Then using LINQ, we can just select from the table into an `IEnumerable(Of Dependency)`.

```vb
Dim dependencies = DependenciesDataTable.Select().Select(Function(row) New Dependency With {.ValueID = row("ValueID"), .DependentValueID = row("DependentValueID"), .DependencyDescription = row("DependencyDescription")})
```

Then group the results by the ValueID property, and select into a Dictionary

```vb
Dim dependenciesDictionary = dependencies.GroupBy(Function(d) d.ValueID).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) g.Select(Function(v) v).ToList())
```

You would end up with a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Dependency))`

And print them out to be sure

```vb
For Each kvp In dependenciesDictionary
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}")
    For Each v In kvp.Value
        Console.WriteLine($"{vbTab}ValueID: {v.ValueID}, DependentValueID: {v.DependentValueID}, DependencyDescription: {v.DependencyDescription}")
    Next
Next
```

> Key: A
>
>     ValueID: A, DependentValueID: a, DependencyDescription: some text
>
>     ValueID: A, DependentValueID: b, DependencyDescription: some text
>
> Key: B
>
>     ValueID: B, DependentValueID: c, DependencyDescription: some text
>
>     ValueID: B, DependentValueID: d, DependencyDescription: some text
>
>     ValueID: B, DependentValueID: e, DependencyDescription: some text

Comment: Thank you so much!